# GetTemplateChild always returns null

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am using GetTemplateChild as follow, but it always returns NULL. How to fix this?

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "textPoints", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
textPoints = (TextBlock)GetTemplateChild("TextBlock");
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? _Reed Copsey_'s answer is correct for the information you have supplied but if this is still not working then perhaps you could post your control template as that may contain the error.

Comment: In my experience, it is not safe to call `FrameworkElement.GetTemplateChild()` before `FrameworkElement.OnApplyTemplate()` is called.  Try subclassing the control and overriding `OnApplyTemplate()`.

Answer (score 4):

[GetTemplateChild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild.aspx) takes the *name* as a parameter, not the type.  Since your XAML is defined as:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Cyan" 
    x:Name="textPoints"
```

Try passing `"textPoints"` instead of `"TextBlock"` as the name to retrieve:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "textPoints", Type = typeof(TextBlock))]
textPoints = (TextBlock)GetTemplateChild("textPoints");
```

Comment: Thnaks, I tried with below code, I still get same result (i.e, NULL) textPoints = (TextBlock)GetTemplateChild("textPoints"); Am I missing some thinng?

Comment: No, In the below method, public override void OnApplyTemplate(). Other GetTemplateChilds are working. I have problem for only this TextBlock. It's part of <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>. Will GetTemplateChild() work in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to get template child of some other control, from where you are calling GetTemplateChild?

If your ItemsControl is inside some UserControl then GetTemplateChild will not work as children of your UserControl are not part of template child anyway and it will not recursively search every child's template child.

Mostly GetTemplateChild is used in Custom Controls.

Comment: Look at above code, it works for x:Name="PointsList"  but not  x:Name="textPoints".  Can you throw some light?
Will GetTemplateChild() work in this case?

Comment: No it will not work, because GetTemplateChild will only look for named child in current template, your textbox is not inside currny Template it is inside template of template child. You will have to create another custom control derived from ItemsControl, however if your control is inside item template then you will need to also create item container as seperate custom control.

Comment: Template child is kind of private element for current control, only parent owning template can access template child, however you can navigate VisualTree and reach child controls anywhere. Also ItemsControl will have many controls with same name for every item, so how will GetTemplateChild will return which item?

Comment: Thanks, Akash. Is there a quick/dirty way to fix this issue?

Comment: Well I don't think so how you can access but mostly I will create dependency properties and bind them accordingly. Otherwise you can navigate VisualTree.GetChild recurively starting at your ItemsControl